# How to return values from table B by looking up comma separated values in a column in table A

Tags: sql, oracle, lookup, oracle12c

I am not sure if my question makes sense but I will try to explain here. I have two tables

TABLE `SAM (SR PK,CODE)`. Column `CODE` may or may not contain comma separated values.

[image: TABLE SAM]

TABLE `FOO (CODE_VAL PK, CODE_DISP_TX)`

[image: TABLE FOO]

I want to write a select query to give me following output from FOO `WHERE SAM.SR = 3`

[image: Output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix your data model!  Storing lists as strings is a really, really bad idea.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really, really bad decisions.  You can do:

```
select f.*
from foo f
where exists (select 1
              from sam s
              where ',' || code || ',' like '%,' || f.code || ',%'
             );
```

Comment: Thank you, the table has only 5 list values and no more would be added in future, hence those are being stored as lists. But I get what you are saying. Thanks a lot!